# What is the formula for calculating the no load current of a 3-phase motor?

Tags: current, motor, current-measurement, three-phase

I am looking for the formula, not a rule of thumb. Is there a way to calculate the no-load current?

Comment: It depends on the frequency, eddy current losses, leakage inductance, no-load mechanical power due to friction and windage, any saturation artifacts and stator inductance etc.. Have you studied the equivalent circuit?

Comment: If only everything in the world could be described with a *formula*. Understanding **how** something works is **crucial** in being able to determine **when** you can use a formula and when you can't.

Comment: @Andy aka. It even depends on speed. Heavily.

Comment: @Janka the OP asked for no-load current and no-load speed can be reasonably estimated.

Comment: At steady state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both [Andy aka](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/20218/andy-aka) and [Bimpelrekkie](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/77865/bimpelrekkie) have commented, there is no useful formula because there are far too many variables both known and unknown. It depends on the design and type (not all motors are induction) of the motor and how well it has been maintained. By far the easiest way of finding out is to get yourself a clamp on ammeter (readily available from multiple sources) and actually measure it on the particular motor in which you are interested.

Comment: I accept that as an answer. Back on my head I had feeling that the best way is to measure it. I